# Calling Paytm SDK using Appcelerator IOS module

Tags: ios, objective-c, titanium, appcelerator, paytm

I need to Integrate Paytm payment gateway from an Appcelerator project for IOS devices. So I was thinking to use the mobile module to call the SDK. I can build and run their sample SDK using Xcode project and get the result, but having difficulties to implement in my modules. From my understanding:

1. The SDK is trying to call a webview and send the data then get response from it.
2. In the SDK ViewController, it extends to `UIViewController <PGTransactionDelegate>` but the module is extended to `TiModule`. My guess is that I need to create a ViewController and call it from the module, but somehow it always failed when I build the Appcelerator project using that module. The cause is probably this line in the module function (if I comment it, I can build the project and get the value) :

   ```
   -(id)makePayment:(id)args {
       ViewController *controller = [[ViewController alloc] init];
       [[TiApp app] showModalController:controller animated:YES];
       NSString *orderID = [args objectAtIndex:0];
       return orderID;
   }
   ```

Is there anyone who able to integrate Appcelerator with Paytm SDK? Any leads or subtle example is very much appreciated.

Paytm SDK : https://github.com/Paytm-Payments/Paytm_iOS_App_Kit

Appcelerator version 4.10

Titanium SDK version 6.1.2.GA

Xcode version 9.1

TBH I am new to both iOS and Appcelerator, but this is client's requirement.

Comment: the appcelerator version you mention is for Appcelerator Studio, not the SDK. You should probably update your question